# Qt Designer: How to lock window size?

Tags: python, qt, qt-designer

So Qt Designer has this feature where you can resize the window you're working on. And that's fine and dandy, but every now and then, I accidentally drag it, and the window gets larger or smaller than I wanted it to be. The undo action doesn't undo the resizing, so that's a bummer. Also setting max and min sizes for the central widget doesn't do anything to fix this issue.

Is there a way I can have the window size locked?

Here's a demo:
[image: demo]

Comment: Resizes will appear in the undo stack if you click the red arrow next to the geometry field in the Property Editor, or click Adjust Size (Ctrl+J).

Answer (score 0):

Use `QWidget::setFixedSize(w, h)` for explicitly set width and height or `QLayout::setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize)` if you want the fixed size to be determined automatically based on content.